# Fhir json - how to suppress attributtes (ex. @Value, @id) in java app

Tags: json, xml, hl7-fhir

I have a REST API that needs to produce both Fhir xml and Fhir json. I generated java classes using xsd.  XML works 100%. however, the json object looks funny as it includes attributes which I'd like to suppress.
I have specified on my REST API: @Produces({"application/json+fhir",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})

XML output:

```
    <Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta>
    <versionId value="urn:uuid:b6bfc48a-7b03-4bf3-ba94-d05a3b52979a"/>
    <lastUpdated value="2017-07-10T08:32:44.670+02:00"/>
</meta>
<type value="collection"/>
<entry>
    <resource>
        <Coverage>
            <id value="47000340200"/>
            <subscriber>
                <display value="AB SMITH"/>
            </subscriber>
            <period>
                <start value="2017-01-01"/>
            </period>
            <payor>
                <display value="XXX040TXX"/>
            </payor>
            <grouping>
                <extension url="some URL">
                    <valueUri value="Hyperlink goes here"/>
                </extension>
                <group value="XXX"/>
                <groupDisplay value="XXX MEDICAL FUND"/>
                <plan value="OPT1"/>
                <planDisplay value="OPTION1"/>
                <class value="Active"/>
            </grouping>
        </Coverage>
    </resource>
</entry>
```

JSON output:

```
    {"Bundle": {
"meta":    {
    "versionId": {"@value": "urn:uuid:b6bfc48a-7b03-4bf3-ba94-d05a3b52979a"},
    "lastUpdated": {"@value": "2017-07-10T08:32:44.670+02:00"}
},
"type": {"@value": "collection"},
"entry":    [
    {"resource": {"Coverage":       {
        "id": {"@value": "47000340200"},
        "subscriber": {"display": {"@value": "AB SMITH"}},
        "period": {"start": {"@value": "2017-01-01"}},
        "payor": {"display": {"@value": "XXX040TXX"}},
        "grouping":          {
            "extension":             {
                "@url": "some URL",
                "valueUri": {"@value": "Hyperlink goes here"}
            },
            "group": {"@value": "XXX"},
            "groupDisplay": {"@value": "XXX MEDICAL FUND"},
            "plan": {"@value": "OPT1"},
            "planDisplay": {"@value": "OPTION1"}
        }
    }}}
]
```

}}

How do I get rid of the "@Value" attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The FHIR XML and JSON (and TTL) syntaxes are all tuned to their syntax and thus manifest a slightly different model.  If you try running an instance with extensions on a simple type (date, boolean, etc.), you'll find even more significant differences in your generated object model.  If you generate your object model from the XML schema, the JSON schema or the OWL, you'll find there's a decent chunk of hand-coding you'll have to add on afterwards to generate and parse the other syntaxes correctly.  The alternative is to use one of the existing reference implementations - those handle the conversion for you and provide a whole bunch of helper classes and methods that might also be helpful for you.  The reference implementations can be found on the [downloads](http://hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html) page.